# How to check if a string is an object's instance variable or not?

Tags: objective-c

I have one question about the variables of an object, I would like to know if I can check if a string is an object's instance variable or not?
Below, an example to illustrate my issue :

I have an object - MyObject.h :

```
@interface MyObject :  NSObject  
{
    //Variables
    id myVariable1;
    id myVariable2;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) id myVariable1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) id myVariable2;
```

And I have also an array list:

```
NSArray * myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"myVariable1",@"myVariable2",@"myVariable3",@"myVariable4",nil];
```

I would like to know if it's possible to determinate which strings in the array list aren't defined as variable in the object MyObject.
=> myVariable3 and myVariable4 for this case.

I tried to use "isKindOfClass", "isMemberOfClass", "valueForKeyPath", "valueForKey" but without success... Let me know if you have some advices to resolve my problem :)

Comment: This has nothing to do with instance! My first edit was wrong and I used "method" this is asking if "How to check if an object has a particular *property*" -- *not "instance"* as that is just the name of the given property (or method, oops, on me for that, fingers too fast). Please update accordingly.

Comment: You probably mean "instance variable" and not "instance name"?!

Comment: You might want to edit your original post to better reflect what it is you really mean.

Comment: It might also help to know what it is you're trying to do. While what you're asking is not impossible, chances are there may be a more straightforward way to go about it.

Comment: Yes you're right @AliSoftware, I mean "instance variable".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the properties aren't using a custom setter name, you could do:

```
MyObject *object = ...;
for (NSString *name in myArray) {
  SEL getterName = NSSelectorFromString(name);
  if ([object respondsToSelector:getterName]) {
    NSLog(@"MyObject has a method named %@", getterName);
  } else {
    NSLog(@"MyObject does not have a method named %@", getterName);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a nice solution. Although this only works with exposed ivars.

Comment: @Eimantas what do you mean? this is checking for the presence of a method, not for an ivar, and will work regardless of whether the method is declared in a private category or not. Nothing is safe from the runtime... ;)

Comment: the OP is asking about instance variables. If I declare instance variable, but do not expose it via `@property` statement or custom getter - I won't be able to "detect" it outside the object with this approach.

Comment: @Eimantas of course. Because this is checking for methods.  Checking for actual instance variable names would be more more complex (but still doable).

Answer (score 1):

I would create an object to use for comparison using the NSClassFromString class.

```
if ([myClass isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(myClassString)] {
   // class matches string
} else {
   // class doesn't match
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to check if values in the array are properties of some object. As in your case the `valueForKey:` should have worked only if `myInstance1` and `myInstance2` are non-nil objects. You'd just need to implement `- (id)valueForUndefinedKey:` method to return `nil` and all would be fine and dandy.

You can also try using `object_getInstanceVariable` method while iterating through an array and fetching each possible instance variable separately. I believe that undeclared instances should return `NULL` pointer (as opposed to `nil` instances that are declared but undefined).